# Unable to Access WordPress Admin Panel After Theme Upload

Tags: php, wordpress

In WordPress, After uploading customized theme, i am unable to access WordPress admin panel. Following URL is being showed. Can anybody help whats the problem exactly?
It is showing following url
http://creativedesignwork.com/demo/premiumhostingreviews/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fpremiumhostingreviews.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
when i am entering http://premiumhostingreviews.com/wp-admin

Comment: Enter your username and password and try login. This is the page http://creativedesignwork.com/demo/premiumhostingreviews/wp-login.php load first when you go for admin panel. So the URL you shown is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

you need to enter you wordpress **username** and **password** to enter Admin Panel

Comment: obviously, but due to redirection there are no fields appearing.